# Using a function to define which rectangular node to send an agent

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to utilize a function that will read the current RectangularNode location of a pallet agent in a queue, return that value, and then utilize that value in a MoveTo block. The pallet agent does have a variable v_palletCurrentNode that is a RectangularNode type. I've built a simplified version of my model in the images and wrote what the errors are. I don't seem to be referring to the nodes in the correct syntax, if anyone could help. Or if there is a simpler solution I haven't been able to find, please advise. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

There is an error on the Action v_palletCurrentNode cannot be resolved or is not a field. v_palletCurrentNode also has an error that GIS cannot be resolved to a type

There is an error on the Node: f_moveToNextPallet cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: Also, pls always share the error msg you get, helps a ton

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question to include the error message.

Comment: focus on 1 error per issue, much easier to help :). So best ask another question for the 2nd error and edit this one for the 1st :) Some tips to help us help you: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

`findFirst(queue)` does not make sense. The `findFirst` wants a collection and a condition (check the API help with code-complete).

If you want the first Pallet agent in a queue, you can use `queue.get(0)`

HOWEVER: this will throw an error if there is nobody in the `queue`.

To avoid that, ensure to only call the code above `if (queue.size()>0)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Benjamin for the suggestion with the `queue.get(0)`
I will also note that the delayForklift is stopped within the queue block, which calls On enter f_precheck():

```
Forklift fl = findFirst(delayForklift, a->a.v_inUse==false);
if (fl==null) {
    traceln("Forklift is a constraint");
    return;
}

fl.v_inUse = true;
delayForklift.stopDelay(fl);
```

My thought process was good, but I missed some Java semicolons and parenthesis.

Under the source blocks, On at exit should be `agent.v_palletCurrentNode = Source;`

In the moveTo block, the Node equation should be `f_moveToNextPallet()`

The function f_moveToNextPallet is

```
Pallet pl = queue.get(0);
return pl.v_palletCurrentNode;
```